# Is there a way to shade between two vertical functions that never touch in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-science

I'm currently reconstructing a temperature profile for a project which displays the altitude on the y-axis and temperature fluctuation on the x-axis similar to as shown:

[image: The temperature profile with +/- 2-sigma error bounds]

In the middle of the plot there is a thick line which represents an interpolated/simulated temperature profile. On the right and left sides of the interpolated profile are error bounds, basically actual data with a +/- error value on it. I'd like to shade between these error bounds showing that the interpolated temperature profile lies within these bounds.

The problem however, is that they never touch so essentially they have different x-values. They are also running vertically, so both `plt.fill_between` and `axvspan`  (which only makes a rectangle) don't work. I've tried reversing the order of some of the arguments thinking because I'm plotting vertically it would work like:

```py
plt1.plot(data, altitude, 'b') #Make the first plot show the temperature profile
plt1.plot(maxSigma, rawalt, 'r', linewidth = 0.3)
plt1.plot(minSigma, rawalt, 'g', linewidth = 0.3)
plt1.fill_between(rawalt, minSigma, maxSigma)
```

but in hindsight that might have been a dumb shot in the dark on my part. I'm stumped.

Comment: Use `fill_betweenx`

Comment: That worked! I can't believe I never found that when looking! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59688223/is-there-a-way-to-shade-between-two-vertical-functions-that-never-touch-in-matpl#comment105533429_59688223) by [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest), here is a complete example showing the usage of [`matplotlib.pyplot.fill_betweenx`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_betweenx.html),

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,8))

n = 200
x = [0.0]
xa = []
xe = []
# Generate some data with a random, accumulating jitter
for i in range(n-1):
    x.append((np.random.random()-0.5)+x[i-1])
ma = 10
# Add some variable error on each side of the generated data
# and use a running average to smooth the generated data
for i in range(n-ma):
    xa.append(sum(x[i:i+ma])/float(ma))
    xe.append([xa[i]-2+(np.random.random()-0.5)*0.25,xa[i]+2+(np.random.random()-0.5)*0.25])

y = np.linspace(10,0,n-ma)
xe = np.array(xe)
plt.plot(xa, y, lw=0.75)
plt.fill_betweenx(y, xe[:,0], xe[:,1], alpha=0.4)
plt.show()
```

[image]